# How to add Admin Access Specific Page in Cakephp2.x

Tags: cakephp, authorize

I want to restrict the admin page to specific user. But I don't want to use with Database Table to restrict this. I saw something on some webpage like this below image.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xo4tus52AZ4MQNoAiWdtkOKoA9nZOPSf/view?usp=sharing

Some said that is used with .htaccess. But I can't find exactly what I want on google. Please help me to with this.

Thanks You.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use DB, then create custom Basic Auth Object. Store login data in php file, etc.

**https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects**

for example code:

**https://gist.github.com/rchrd2/c94eb4701da57ce9a0ad4d2b00794131**

**http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/auth.htm**